# AssertionError: group argument must be None for now

Tags: python, multithreading

I start to learn python and multithreading. I am trying to do the dining philosopher problem. I use class philosophers(threading.thread). But when I put in some sample and create threads, it has error AssertionError: group argument must be None for now.

```
import threading
import time
from random import randint

exitFlag = 0

class philosophers(threading.Thread):
    
    def __int__(self, phi, hungry, eat):
        threading.Thread.__int__(self)
        #super(philosophers.self)__int__()
        self.phi = phi
        self.hungry = hungry
        self.eat = eat
        
    def hungry(self):
        time.sleep(self.hungry)
        print("Philosopher" +(self.phi) + "is hungry and want to eat" + "\n")
        startEat()
        
    def startEat(self):
        left = self.phi
        right = (self.phi+1)%5
        left.acquire()
        if right.locked():
            left.release()
        else:
            right.acquire()
        time.sleep(self.eat)
        
        right.release()
        left.release()
        print("Philosopher" +(self.phi) + "is finished" + "\n")

#def run()
thread1 = philosophers(1, 5, 3)
thread2 = philosophers(2, 4, 2)
#thread3 = philosophers(3, 6, 7)
#thread4 = philosophers(4, 2, 8)
#thread5 = philosophers(5, 3, 4)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
#thread3.start()
#thread4.start()
#thread5.start()

thread1.join()
thread2.join()
#thread3.join()
#thread4.join()
#thread5.join()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: in standard `Thread` you has to use named argument - `Thread(target=..., args=...)` because if you don't use named arguments then it will assign values to first argument which expect `group`.

Comment: your class makes no sense. When you run `thread.start()` then it create new thread in system and it runs `thread.run()`.  But you don't have `run()` in your class so it will runs default `run()` which does nothing if you don't use `target=..`. Thread will not run `hungry` or `startEat` because it doesn't know these function - you should rename `def hungry` into `def run`

Comment: your main problem is type: it has to be `__init__` instead of `__int__` (in two places)

Comment: `left` and `right` are normal numbers `int` - you can't use them with `acquire`, `locked`, `release`. You need objects [threading.Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is simple typo: it has to be `__init__` instead of `__int__` (in two places)

But there are other probles.

When you execute `thread.start()` then it create thread in system and executes `thread.run()` so you have to rename `def hungry` into `def run`

`left` and `right` are normal numbers `int`. You can't use them with `acquire`, `locked`, `release`. You need objects [threading.Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock) for this.

It is not mistake but you could keep `threads` on list and then it is simpler to use `start()` and `join()` on all `threads`. And you don't have to change this part of code even if you change number of `threads` on list.

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

Last problem is that I'm not sure if your algorithm is correct.

As for me `Philosopner` can eat (`time.sleep(self.eat)`) even if he doesn't have both forks.

And at start `left.acquire()` can give `False` but you don't check it.

**EDIT:**

I added more `print()` to see values in variable and which part of code is executed and I get:

```
Philosopher 4 is hungry and want to eat
Philosopher 4 left fork: True
Philosopher 4 right fork: True
Philosopher 4 is eating
Philosopher 5 is hungry and want to eat
Philosopher 2 is hungry and want to eat
Philosopher 2 left fork: True
Philosopher 2 right fork: True
Philosopher 2 is eating
Philosopher 1 is hungry and want to eat
Philosopher 1 left fork: True
Philosopher 1 doesn't have forks
Philosopher 3 is hungry and want to eat
Philosopher 2 is finished
Philosopher 3 left fork: True
Philosopher 3 doesn't have forks
Philosopher 1 is finished
Philosopher 4 is finished
Philosopher 5 left fork: True
Philosopher 5 right fork: True
Philosopher 5 is eating
Philosopher 3 is finished
Philosopher 5 is finished
```

and there are `1 doesn't have forks`, `3 doesn't have forks` but they finish without eating.

It may need some loop to try again get forks.

---

```
import threading
import time


class Philosopher(threading.Thread):  # PEP8: `UpperCaseNames` for classes.
                                      # PEP8: This class describes single Philospher so it should have name without `s` at the end
    
    def __init__(self, phi, hungry, eat, locks): #, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__() #*args, **kwargs)
        self.phi = phi
        self.hungry = hungry
        self.eat = eat
        self.locks = locks

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(self.hungry)
        print(f"Philosopher {self.phi} is hungry and want to eat")
        self.start_eat()  # need `self.`
        
    def start_eat(self):
        left = self.locks[self.phi-1]   # Python uses indexes `[0..4]` instead of `[1..5]`
        right = self.locks[self.phi%5]  # Python uses indexes `[0..4]` instead of `[1..5]`
        
        result = left.acquire()
        print(f"Philosopher {self.phi} left fork:", result)

        if right.locked():
            left.release()
            print(f"Philosopher {self.phi} doesn't have forks")
        else:
            result = right.acquire()            
            print(f"Philosopher {self.phi} right fork:", result)
            print(f"Philosopher {self.phi} is eating")
        time.sleep(self.eat)
        
        if right.locked():
            right.release()
        if left.locked():
            left.release()
        
        print(f"Philosopher {self.phi} is finished")


# --- main ---

# 5 locks for 5 Philosophers
locks = [threading.Lock() for _ in range(5)]

threads = [
    Philosopher(1, 5, 3, locks),
    Philosopher(2, 4, 2, locks),
    Philosopher(3, 6, 7, locks),
    Philosopher(4, 2, 8, locks),
    Philosopher(5, 3, 4, locks),
]    

for t in threads:
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

---

**EDIT:**

It seems this algorithm works correctly.

```
def start_eat(self):
    left = self.locks[self.phi-1]   # Python uses indexes `[0..4]` instead of `[1..5]`
    right = self.locks[self.phi%5]  # Python uses indexes `[0..4]` instead of `[1..5]`

    while True:    
        if not left.locked():    
            result = left.acquire()
            #print(f"Philosopher {self.phi} left fork:", result)
            if right.locked():
                left.release()
                #print(f"Philosopher {self.phi} doesn't have forks")
            else:
                result = right.acquire()            
                #print(f"Philosopher {self.phi} right fork:", result)
                print(f"Philosopher {self.phi} is eating")
                time.sleep(self.eat)
                right.release()
                left.release()
                print(f"Philosopher {self.phi} is finished")
                break
```

Result:

```
Philosopher 4 is hungry and want to eat
Philosopher 4 is eating
Philosopher 5 is hungry and want to eat
Philosopher 2 is hungry and want to eat
Philosopher 2 is eating
Philosopher 1 is hungry and want to eat
Philosopher 3 is hungry and want to eat
Philosopher 2 is finished
Philosopher 1 is eating
Philosopher 1 is finished
Philosopher 4 is finished
Philosopher 5 is eating
Philosopher 3 is eating
Philosopher 5 is finished
Philosopher 3 is finished
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I try it again in my lap.